# How to monitor/wait on array of objects?

Tags: c#

I am using concurrent bag to store a set of objects. I want to implement something like
if(an object is present)
return it
else wait until one get free, if it does not get free in a specific time throw an exception.

if(object has been returned)
add to bag

I was thinking to use monitors but monitor can wait on a specific object. I want to wait till any of them is free. How can I implement it?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Here is an msdn article explaining how to use concurrent bag to create an object pool. The behavior creates a new object instead of waiting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458671%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am thinking on these lines ,While returning objects I am checking if the bag has turned empty. If yes I am setting a variable true. The next thread if comes for an object and finds the variable true, it needs to wait for a specific time till it turns true. I need to use locking here if two threads come asking for an object

Comment: @Gusdor : Due to limitation of resources, I cannot create as many objects as needed. Thanks for the articles anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the msdn example [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff458671%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class FiniteObjectPool<T>: IDisposable
{
    System.Threading.AutoResetEvent m_Wait = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);

    private ConcurrentBag<T> _objects;

    public FiniteObjectPool()
    {
        _objects = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    }

    public T GetObject()
    {
        T item;
        while(!_objects.TryTake(out item))
        {
            m_Wait.WaitOne(); //an object was not available, wait until one is
        }

        return item;
    }

    public void PutObject(T item)
    {
        _objects.Add(item);
        m_Wait.Set(); //signal a waiting thread that object may now be available
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        m_Wait.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**EDIT - example usage with 'Context' idiom wrapper**

```
class Program
{
    public class FiniteObjectPoolContext<T>: IDisposable
    {
        FiniteObjectPool<T> m_Pool = new FiniteObjectPool<T>();
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public FiniteObjectPoolContext(FiniteObjectPool<T> pool)
        {
            m_Pool = pool;
            Value = pool.GetObject(); //take an object out - this will block if none is available
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            m_Pool.PutObject(Value); //put the object back because this context is finished
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FiniteObjectPool<int> pool = new FiniteObjectPool<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pool.PutObject(i);
        }

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            int id = i;
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Running task " + id);
                    using (var con = new FiniteObjectPoolContext<int>(pool))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Task " + id + " got object from pool: " + con.Value);
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Task " + id + " is finished with pool object: " + con.Value);
                    }
                }));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Notice the latency injected by the thread synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: Instead of TryTake , soemthing like While(!_objects.TryPeek(out item)) would also do the trick. But to wait an specific amount of time, I believe we need to use events based triggering for it.

Comment: @user3747969 I'm not a big fan of the Get/Put idiom. It seems like a little _whoopsie_ somewhere could decrement your pool permenantly. I expect that you would wrap the pool with something specific if you wanted to create a `using(var context = Pool.GetContext()){/*work*/}` programming model.

Comment: @user3747969 the problem with `TryPeek` is that it does not remove the object from the bag. You have to maintain a list of available objects somewhere - using the contents of the bag is a good way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Semaphores for the operations that you want to do. .NET has two implementations for Semaphores. Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim, both can be used to implement many threads trying to access a pool of resources.